# How to read a set of numbered txt files using loop in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a set of txt files with names a00, a01, a02, .. a0N, a10, a11, ... aNN. Each file contains 3-column data X,Y,Z. How to read the data efficiently such that some array f[m,n,:,:,:] contains the X,Y,Z data of file amn?

Comment: loop over the folder with all the files. Parse each file into a pandas dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
from glob import glob

def generate_list_of_files():
    return glob('a[0-9][0-9].txt')

def generate_row(line):
    empty_list=[None,None,None]
    for i in range (3):
        empty_list[i]=line.split(',')[i]
    return empty_list


def parse_file(one_file):
    list_of_dict=[]
    for line in one_file.readlines():
        list_of_dict.extend(generate_row(line))
    return list_of_dict

def process_files(files):
    final_list=[]
    for one_file in files:
        f=open(one_file,'r') #f means file descriptor
        final_list.extend(parse_file(f))
        f.close()
    return final_list

if __name__=='__main__':
    files=generate_list_of_files()
    print(process_files(files))
```